# storing each word in a 2d string C

Tags: c, string, getchar

i want to store each word in a 2d string. The code i wrote is working with no errors the only issue is when there are two spaces or more, it stores the space as a word. If anyone knows how can i fix this

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define IN  1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    char words[100][1000];
    int i=0, k, j=0, m=0;
    int state = OUT;
    int nw = 0;


    while((k = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if((isspace(k)!= 0)|| (ispunct(k)!= 0))
        {
            state = OUT;
            words[i][j] = '\0';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        } 
        else
        {
            words[i][j++]= k;
            if(state == OUT)
            {
                state = IN;
                nw++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to skip all the whitespace before entering a new word by considering the last character. Also you can simplify checking for space and punctuation.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define IN  1
#define OUT 0

int main()
{
    char words[100][1000];
    int i=0, k, j=0, m=0;
    int state = OUT;
    int nw = 0;

    int last_char = ' ';
    while((k = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if((isspace(k)|| ispunct(k)) && !isspace(last_char))
        {
            state = OUT;
            words[i][j] = '\0';
            i++;
            j = 0;
        } 
        else if (!isspace(k))
        {
            words[i][j++]= k;
            if(state == OUT)
            {
                state = IN;
                nw++;
            }
        }
        last_char = k;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get the idea but still when I print out the words it prints out the spaces too

Comment: @Moe You also need to add the check for space in the else condition. I've updated the answer.